# Way to get timestamp of last activity for all Slack users

Tags: python, slack-api

I am building a Python script which retrieves a set of information for all Slack users of the organization that I work. Currently, I was asked by the stakeholders to retrieve the last time that our organization's users were active on Slack. I came across the [users.getPresence](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.getPresence) method but this can only return a timestamp for the owner of the token. Has anybody worked on that before? Thanks.

Comment: I would look into Events API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends a bit how you define "active on Slack".

If getting the date and time a user was logged in last is enough, take a look at [`team.accessLogs`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs), which will give you the timestamp of the last login for every user (`date_last`).

This will not reflect whether the user performed any activity, e.g. posting a message or uploading a file though.

However, note that this API method works for paid plans only.

Comment: Thank you @erik It can be a reasonable solution for the moment. Otherwise, I should create an app, integrate it with Slack and use [RTM](https://api.slack.com/rtm) to track user's activity and post updates to the server whenever they connect/disconnect.