# Get information when members were last online

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am trying to get information from the Slack API when members were last online (not using paid plan).

I tried https://api.slack.com/methods/users.getPresence and the "last_activity" but it seems it only returns a timestamp if the user is currently online.

Is there any other call to make which returns their last online activity without getting the paid plan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to get timestamp of last activity for all Slack users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280153/way-to-get-timestamp-of-last-activity-for-all-slack-users)

Comment: ^^ That is the only solution that I am aware of, but yes it only works on paid plans.

Comment: You could maybe log information from all message events, but that would be incomplete, since it would only include users that posted on public channels.